# Python AWS Boto3 SAML Auth Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

Hi I am trying to find all AWS EC2 instances with port 22 0.0.0.0/0 open. I have the below code but keep running into an auth handling error below. It seems like boto cant recognize i authenticated. I have been searching around but cannot find how to handle this error. Any ideas on how to handle the error below?

```
import sys
import boto
from boto import ec2
from boto import sns
import os
import boto3


# Call the saml API Key Retreiver - Must be stored in C:\Temp
os.system('"C:/Temp/apikeyretriever_windows_386.exe"')

# Set Profile to SAML
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='saml')



connection = ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
connSNS = boto.sns.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
sg = connection.get_all_security_groups('us-east-1')

listOfInstances = ""
messages = "Following Instances have port 22 open"


def getTag(instanceId):
    reservations = connection.get_all_instances(filters={'instance_id': instanceId})
    for r in reservations:
        for i in r.instances:
            return i.tags['Name']


try:

    for securityGroup in sg:
        for rule in securityGroup.rules:

            global instanceId;

            if (rule.from_port == '22' and rule.to_port == '22') and '0.0.0.0/0' in str(rule.grants):
                for instanceid in securityGroup.instances():
                    listOfInstances += "Instance Name : " + getTag(instanceId.split(':')[
                                                                       1]) + "\t State:" + instanceid.state + "\t SecurityGroup:" + securityGroup.name + "\n"

                    connSNS.publish(topic='sns-arn-endpoint', message=messages + "\n" + listOfInstances,
                                    subject='ProjectName : Server List with Port 22 Open')

except:
    print('Some Error occurred : ')
    print
    sys.exc_info()
    connSNS.publish(topic='sns-arn-endpoint', message=sys.exc_info(), subject='script ended with error')
```

The error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "port.py", line 17, in <module>
        connection = ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto\ec2\__init__.py", line 6
    6, in connect_to_region
        connection_cls=EC2Connection, **kw_params)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto\regioninfo.py", line 218
    , in connect
        return region.connect(**kw_params)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto\regioninfo.py", line 288
    , in connect
        return self.connection_cls(region=self, **kw_params)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto\ec2\connection.py", line
     103, in __init__
        profile_name=profile_name)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line 110
    0, in __init__
        provider=provider)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.py", line 569
    , in __init__
        host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto\auth.py", line 1021, in
    get_auth_handler
        'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names)))
    boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handl
    ers were checked. ['HmacAuthV4Handler'] Check your credentials
```

Comment: What auth error. Post a stacktrace or be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you're getting from the stack trace looks like your script can't find the STS token, which I'm assuming is what apikeyretriever_windows_386.exe is supposed to create and stash for you, to log into the API under a profile called "saml" in your AWS Credentials/Config file.